# Wait for callback in javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, wait

I'm trying to create a function that returns a object with information of a callback:

```
var geoloc;

var successful = function (position) {
    geoloc = {
        longitude: position.coords.longitude,
        latitude: position.coords.latitude
    };
};

var getLocation = function () {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successful, function () {
        alert("fail");
    });

    return geoloc;
};
```

How can I do this? The function `getLocation` return null value before `successful` is executed.

Thanks!

Comment: You have too many `}` in `getLocation`.

Comment: You have too many `l`'s and too few `s`'s in `successful`... ;)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Callbacks are used because the function is asynchronous.  The callback runs at some point in the future.

So, yes `getLocation` returns before the callback is triggered.  That's how asynchronous methods work.

You cannot wait for the callback, that's not how it works.  You can add a callback to `getLocation`, that runs once it's done.

```
var getLocation = function(callback){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos){
        succesfull(pos);
        typeof callback === 'function' && callback(geoloc);
    }, function(){
        alert("fail");
    });
};
```

Now instead of doing `var x = getLocation()` and expecting a return value, you call it like this:

```
getLocation(function(pos){
    console.log(pos.longitude, pos.latitude);
});
```

Comment: It is very interesting! The example works great and is perfect for my project.

Thanks for helping me learn javascript.

Comment: Stumbled upon this answer, I'm trying to stream location data using websockets and this was tripping me up. This is definitely a step in the right directions, is there anything else I should be mindful of, as I'm trying to do the above with either `setTimeout` or `setInterval` to send location data every `X` seconds. Is this an advisable approach?

Answer (score 20):

I would recommend the approach in Rocket's answer. However, if you really wanted to, you could trigger the rest of your code when the `getLocation` finishes by using a jQuery deferred object. This will give you more fine-grained control than just using the callbacks provided by `getCurrentPosition`.

```
// create a new deferred object
var deferred = $.Deferred();

var success = function (position) {
    // resolve the deferred with your object as the data
    deferred.resolve({
        longitude: position.coords.longitude,
        latitude: position.coords.latitude
    });
};

var fail = function () {
    // reject the deferred with an error message
    deferred.reject('failed!');
};

var getLocation = function () {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, fail); 

    return deferred.promise(); // return a promise
};

// then you would use it like this:
getLocation().then(
    function (location) {
         // success, location is the object you passed to resolve
    }, 
    function (errorMessage) {
         // fail, errorMessage is the string you passed to reject
    });
```

Comment: I've never actually messed with `Deferred`, but this looks pretty neat. +1

Comment: @Rocket i just started messing with it yesterday so now i'm trying to get every question to look like a nail so i can use my new hammer :P