# JavaScript: Can't get value of variable from another function

Tags: javascript

I'm facing issues getting value of a variable from another function. I'm trying to get the **distance of the place from current position in google maps**, but using `Haversine Formula` of calculating distance.

My HTML:

```
<p>
  <script>
  lat = "<?php echo $atm_row_data->latitude;?>";
  lng = "<?php echo $atm_row_data->longitude;?>";
  dist = getDistance(lat, lng);
  document.write(dist);
  </script>
</p>
```

My JavaScript:

```
var curPosition;
var lat, lng;

/**** get current position ****/
function getPosition() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showCurrentPosition);
    } else {
        alert('Geolocation is not supported by this browser.');
    }
}

function showCurrentPosition(position) {
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lng = position.coords.longitude;
    curPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    console.log('curPosition: '+curPosition); <--- this works
}

/******** Haversine Formula of Getting Distance ********/
var rad = function(x) {
  return x * Math.PI / 180;
};

function getDistance(lt, lg) {
    console.log(curPosition); <--- this shows undefined
    var p1 = curPosition;
    var R = 6378137; // Earth’s mean radius in meter
    var dLat = rad(lt - p1.lat());
    var dLong = rad(lg - p1.lng());
    var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
    Math.cos(rad(p1.lat())) * Math.cos(rad(lt)) *
    Math.sin(dLong / 2) * Math.sin(dLong / 2);
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    var d = R * c;
    if (d >= 1000)
        return Math.round( (d / 1000) * 100) / 100 + "Km";
    else
        return Math.round( (d * 100) / 100) + "m";
};
/******** END Haversine Formula of Getting Distance ********/
```

Where am I going wrong?

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Check the console. Are you getting errors? Is it that you're not getting the correct answer? Nothing?

Comment: I guess you never call `showCurrentPosition`, so the `curPosition` remains undefined.

Comment: The problem is most likely variable scope. You are trying to access a variable outside scope. Try defining `curPosition` in the beginning outside any functions.

Comment: Console throws: undefined

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined

Comment: @mrak In getPosition() function, the showCurrentPosition() is called `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showCurrentPosition);`

Comment: @h4kl0rd but `getPosition()` is **not** called before calling `getDistance()`.

Comment: In `getPosition` (at least in the code you posted), you are not calling the function `showCurrentPosition`. Check your syntax: Its `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showCurrentPosition)` which means, that you pass the reference to the showCurrentPosition function, but you are not calling it.

Comment: @mrak within the geolocation showCurrentPosition is passed as callback function and called when position is available, thats how navigation geoloation.getcurrentposition and watchposition work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing the google api, , navigator.geolocation has a callback, so showcurrentPostion is the callback function, but the thing is u never call
getPosition() <--

```
function getDistance(lt, lg) {
    console.log(curPosition); <--- this shows undefined <---- so this will always be undefined
    var p1 = curPosition;
    var R = 6378137; // Earth’s mean radius in meter
    var dLat = rad(lt - p1.lat());
    var dLong = rad(lg - p1.lng());
    var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
    Math.cos(rad(p1.lat())) * Math.cos(rad(lt)) *  <--- see comment
    Math.sin(dLong / 2) * Math.sin(dLong / 2); 
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    var d = R * c;
    if (d >= 1000)
        return Math.round( (d / 1000) * 100) / 100 + "Km";
    else
        return Math.round( (d * 100) / 100) + "m";
};
```

- comment:  <------ p1 curposition gets an google maps object with lat and long where i know that lat() is not a function so this will fail 
  so even when u get the current position the function above (getDistance()) will fail

Call getPosition first() <--- u need to get the position

edit: i see that u can call console.log and you say it works, so i think its a scoping issue,

I made an example for you -> http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOBMPj 
i'm not able to render the googlemap within the pen, but u can look at the source, on how its done. hope this helps you.

so in order to do this calculation u dont really need google maps u just need the first/ and second coords, but its fun to do something with on on the google map:)

Comment: Can we initiate a chat?

Comment: ive updated my answer, the pen will give you the distance from your current location, to amsterdam :D, copy the source to see how its done,

Ive added the correct formula, with the link from they guy who made all the mathematical calculations (Chris Veness), my code shows u how to calculate the position from point to point, i did not copy all your code into it, only the code that was needed, i namespaced the functions within Maps {}

if this helps , please accept as "ANSWER"

Comment: thanks for your pen, I went through it, but it works for one location not multiple. I'm looping through lots of locations and passing their lats and longs to `getDistance()` to get distance from my current location to these locations.

Comment: @h4kl0rd, then u should u pass the currentlocation and location u wish to calculate the distance to to the getdistance function, from ur loop, so u can get it for all locations. just add it to ur loop , and store it somewhere. - if it works for one, it will work for many

Comment: though i think thats another question ;)

Comment: Passing the lats, longs isn't the issue (see my code). The issue is getting the current position from `getPosition()` - the **curPosition**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88580/discussion-between-danillo2k-and-h4kl0rd).

Comment: `console.log(this.currentLat+', '+this.currentLon);` inside the **distanceToLocation** returns `undefined, undefined`. In the view, this is how I call it: 
`var dist = Object.create(Maps); dist.initialize; dist.distanceToLocation(lat, lng);`. **currentLocation** works fine, **newLocation** returns `undefined`. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Fiddle:)? Please for a closer look

Comment: thats because when u do dist.initializ, the retrieving of the position (getcurrentposition is asynchronous, so the callback get executed when it has its position, or it will throw error), but the function after initialize , dist.distance is sync , so it gets executed before the position is done u should trigger it from the callback function, or u should use a (promise). Create function like (getWhatever() { return a new promise) } once resolved, getWhatever.then dist.distanceloTolocation and example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747440/wait-for-callback-in-javascript (13 votes example)

Comment: made updates according to the example, now throws `Cannot read property 'promise' of undefined`. Check [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h4kl0rd/1qyfax9d/4/)

Comment: please take the time to read your code. look at your fiddle,
first u say this.deferred = $.Deferred(); within initialise, but later u try to use it by calling deferred, (deferred does not exist) its this.deferred

if u you use the deferred example, you could remove this.getLocation from initialise, and instead of calling dist.distanceToLocation, u could to dist.GetLocation().then(function() { here the logic that is in distanceToLocation }) or call the distanceToLocation function itself.

whats in then will happen after the location is resolved, u cannot do getLocation().then; <-- its invalid

Comment: Hi @danillo2k, please check my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h4kl0rd/1qyfax9d/7/), I made some changes and now I the `resolve` returns `undefined`. I tried resolving myself after going through lots of online resources, but was unsuccessful.

Comment: i didnt have the time to debug your code, but by taking a quick look i think this is undefined within the succes, your within the callback, so its not the same scope, so line 72: navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.success, this.fail);  
should be 
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.success.bind(this), this.fail.bind(this));

in order  for this success to have the same scope.

Answer (score 1):

In your script tags, your only call `getDistance(lat,lng)`, but `showCurrentPosition(position)` is never called! So the variable `curPosition` is undefined, because it is **not** defined yet!

You need to call `showCurrentPosition(position)` for the variable `curPosition` to hold a value.

Perhaps calling `getPosition()` at the beginning of your `getDistance()` function could solve the problem, as it seems to call `showCurrentPosition`.

---

Alternative to show the position in HTML (this is just a quick snippet, you can adapt it to whatever you like):

```
function getPositionHTML() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
        curPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
    });
    return curPosition;
}
```

It basically does the same thing as your other function, but it relies on the Single Reponsibility Principle, so once you called this function you can manipulate `curPosition` however you want.

Comment: I have called the `getPosition()` in `initialize()` function and tried to call it before `getDistance()` but still throws **undefined**. I just want to display the distance in the html. Maybe there's another way.

Comment: I tried making the edits but still returning **undefined**. It only works if I place `return curPosition` inside the `navigator.geolocation...`, which then returns **undefined** when calling outside the function or from another function.

Comment: @h4kl0rd Then you have two choices: You either do the UI modifications within that function (`getPositionHTML`), or you use a Promise object to make sure the `getCurrentPosition` function has been successfully completed and use a `then` to do the UI modification.