# How to make a for loop wait until callback respond with value

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, settimeout

I have click event which calls `FireCallBackEvents` and from there I pass the array of function which all are callback. Now I want to call `function b()` after `function a()` which gives the result of callback I call through `setTimeout()`. I expect that it will delay in giving result.

Now in below code alert of first function callback is called after function b and c is called.

This is only a sample of my real code.

```
function FireCallBackEvents(){
    generalizeCallBack([a,b,c]);
}

function a(parameter1, parameter2,callback){
    alert("Hello World: " + parameter1 + " : " + parameter2);
    setTimeout(function(){callback("12")},600);
}
function b(parameter1, parameter2,callback){
    alert("Hello World1: " + parameter1 + " : " + parameter2);
    callback("123");
}
function c(parameter1, parameter2, callback){
    alert("Hello World2: " + parameter1 + " : " + parameter2);
    callback("1234");
}

function generalizeCallBack(arrayOfFunctions){
    for(var i = 0; i < arrayOfFunctions.length; i++){
        arrayOfFunctions[i]("1","2",function(we){
            alert(we);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using jQuery "deferred objects": http://www.vasanthk.com/jquery-promises-and-deferred-objects/

Comment: deferred won't help as I am trying to generalize callback function so there will be in ease in understanding as this is the example of 3 functions I have 20 function in callbacks which will result into too many `)};` at the end of the function

Comment: Using deferred will complicate my program more

Comment: Make your functions into promises and then you can do things like `Promise.all(arrayOfPromises)` ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)) if you need to way to react once all of them have completed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wait for callback in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747440/wait-for-callback-in-javascript)

Comment: @CharlieH it is not a duplicate of it as I am particullarly focusing on for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this variant of your last function, which calls it recursively from the callback function you pass:

```
function generalizeCallBack(arrayOfFunctions){
    if (!arrayOfFunctions.length) return; // nothing to do
    var func = arrayOfFunctions.shift(); // extract function to execute
    func("1","2", function(we){
        alert(we);
        generalizeCallBack(arrayOfFunctions); // recurse with shorter array
    });
}
```

Note that this changes the array you pass. If you prefer that the callers keep their array in tact, use `slice` and not `shift`:

```
function generalizeCallBack(arrayOfFunctions){
    if (!arrayOfFunctions.length) return; // nothing to do
    var func = arrayOfFunctions[0]; // get function to execute
    func("1","2", function(we){
        alert(we);
        generalizeCallBack(arrayOfFunctions.slice(1)); // recurse with shorter array
    });
}
```

Since this version takes an array copy at every (recursive) call, we could make it more efficient by only doing that the first time (as suggested by @Alnitak):

```
function generalizeCallBack(arrayOfFunctions){
    function recurse (arrayOfFunctions) {
        if (!arrayOfFunctions.length) return; // nothing to do
        var func = arrayOfFunctions.shift(); // extract first function
        func("1","2", function(we){
            alert(we);
            recurse(arrayOfFunctions); // recurse with shorter array
        });
    }
    // take copy (slice) of array in order not to alter the caller's array:
    recurse(arrayOfFunctions.slice(0));
}
```

This way only one copy is taken of the array. The recursive part works on that same copy, making it shorter as it goes down the recursion chain.

This is the same, but written as an immediately invoked function expression:

```
function generalizeCallBack(arrayOfFunctions){
    (function recurse (arrayOfFunctions) {
        if (!arrayOfFunctions.length) return; // nothing to do
        var func = arrayOfFunctions.shift(); // extract first function
        func("1","2", function(we){
            alert(we);
            recurse(arrayOfFunctions); // recurse with shorter array
        });
        // take copy (slice) of array in order not to alter the caller's array:
    }(arrayOfFunctions.slice(0)));
}
```

Comment: Ya it would make some sense I should try this'

Comment: you could make the second version more efficient by taking a single copy of the array and then performing the pseudo-recursion with a nested IIFE.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Alnitak, I added it to this answer.

Comment: Looks good - could perhaps do with explaining that #2 actually makes a new copy of the array on each iteration

Comment: I think I already mentioned that: *Since this version takes a copy at every call*... I will inject the word "recursive" in it to make it more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

You should not call your array of functions within a loop in your `generalizeCallBack` function. It wouldn't help you delaying later functions (function b and c) from being executed based on the result of an early function (function a) which calls `setTimeout`.

**The `setTimeout` function will only be executed when the browser gets next breathing space. That is right after your function loop.**

The solution is to let your function `a` return a promise and execute other functions (b and c) when the promise is successful.

Comment: If you can read the question I wrote this is a sample code and setTimeout is just because to delay as there will be db operations where I have put setTimeout

Comment: If you can read the answer put your db operation inside a promise and return it. ;)